# Steam games stuck on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, games, steam

I got steam from the repository and installed fine, but then to get it open I had to delete libstdc++.so.6 and after the update it opened fine.

It downloads games and everything, but when i try to play any game, it frezee after like 2 minutes and cant do anything else than kill the process of the game.

I'm kind of noob on Ubuntu so any kind of help will be apreciated.

Comment: What hardware? Namely what graphics card and drivers?

Comment: MSI GX60, with radeon hd 7970m... and just can find 1 privative dirver for AMD CPUs "amd64-microcode"

Comment: There's no AMD proprietary drivers for 16.04. What you have is all you need. If it doesn't work - and it may not considering the age - there's nothing you can do.

Comment: but the games opens and everything... it's just that after a minute stops responding at all

Comment: I'm knot quite sure what worked for now, but I just copied [libsteam_api.so] from one game to [/usr/lib] and [/usr/lib/steam].... and also found in the folder of the games there was an 32 and 64 bits version, used the 64 and all was fine.